# Can the Volterra operator be norm-approximated by nilpotent operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $V$ be the Volterra operator on the Hilbert space $L_2[0,1]$. Then $V$ is bounded and quasinilpotent. Can $V$ be approximated in norm by nilpotent operators?

Comment: The answer is, Yes, apparently. It was shown by C. Apostol and D. Voiculescu in 1974, and independently by D. Herrero in 1974/5, that every quasinilpotent operator on a separable Hilbert space can be norm-approximated by nilpotent operators.